# AngularJS socket.io event forwarding with deferred promise

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, angular-promise

I am using [angular-socket-io](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io) but needed a way to authenticate in the app first before starting the socket.io interface. [I followed this method](https://gist.github.com/jrthib/4ce016449a29811d71b5).

But I need to use event forwarding in the factory [as shown here](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io) like this:

```
socket.forward("event");
```

How can I add forwarding in my factory?

```
.factory('socket', function($rootScope, $timeout, socketFactory, $q, $log) {
  // create a promise instance
  var socket = $q.defer();
  // listen for the authenticated event emitted on the rootScope of
  // the Angular app. Once the event is fired, create the socket and resolve
  // the promise.
  $rootScope.$on('authenticated', function() {

    // resolve in another digest cycle
    $timeout(function() {
      var token = window.localStorage["socket_token"];
      var token_query = 'token=' + token;
      var newSocket = (function() {
        return socketFactory({
          ioSocket: io.connect('http://example.com:3000', {
            query: token_query
          })
        });
      })();
      socket.resolve(newSocket);
    });
  });
  return socket.promise
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add the call to `forward()` before resolving the promise with the created socket:

```
newSocket = (function() { /* ... */ })()
newSocket.forward("event");
socket.resolve(newSocket);
```

Comment: yup it was that simple.

Comment: see if you can help with [this related issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35044402/angularjs-not-executing-deferred-promise-using-angular-socket-io)