# angularjs not executing deferred promise using angular-socket-io

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, angular-promise

After solving [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006814/angularjs-socket-io-event-forwarding-with-deferred-promise) I now have a new issue with angular halting inside a function that's waiting on a socket connection.

Controller:

```
.controller('myCtrl',function($scope, socket) {

  var sendMsg = function(msg) {
    socket.then(function(msg) {
      socket.emit('newMsg', msg);
    });
  }

  //simplified example
  var msg = 'Hi Mom!';
  sendMsg(msg);

});
```

The problem is that `socket.emit()` never gets fired. If I remove `socket.then()` I will get an error `socket.emit is not a function`. We have to wait for socket to be initialized (which is based on successful login in another controller and broadcast through the `socket` factory).  Is this a chicken-egg paradox? How can I fire socket.emit in another function?  Other similar functions work, such as:

```
socket.then(function(socket) {
 socket.on('connect',function() {
   //do something. This works.
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are having two `msg` parameters. However, the second one is the socket:

```
var sendMsg = function(msg) {
    socket.then(function(socket) { // <--
        socket.emit('newMsg', msg);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks it was actually that I have to log out and back in to re-initialize the socket when I make code changes. Then the function works properly.